Rust Arc pointer comparison fails despite same memory address
In Rust, I'm trying to make a group of objects that can be related to one another in a sort of target/dependency chain. I figured I could use a trait and, for each object, assign a "target" as a weak pointer to the next item in the chain. Everything was going as expected until I decided to do some basic unit tests. I wanted to verify if the assigned weak pointer (upgraded to an Arc) was the same as the original instance. However, an assert_eq!() fails when comparing both raw pointers, even though the error message shows the same value for both sides of the equation.
Here is a simplified version of what I did:
use std::{
    fmt::Debug,
    sync::{
        Arc,
        Mutex,
        Weak,
    },
};

pub trait Target: Debug + Send + Sync {
    fn get_target(&self) -> Result<Option<Arc<Mutex<dyn Target>>>, String>;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Parent {
    pub id: u32,
    pub target: Option<Weak<Mutex<dyn Target>>>
}
impl Parent {
    pub fn assign_target<T: Target + Debug + Send + Sync + 'static>(&mut self, target: &Arc<Mutex<T>>) {
        self.target = Some(Arc::downgrade(&(target.clone() as Arc<Mutex<dyn Target>>)));
    }
}
impl Target for Parent {
    fn get_target(&self) -> Result<Option<Arc<Mutex<dyn Target>>>, String> {
        if let None = self.target {
            return Ok(None);
        }

        match self.target.as_ref().unwrap().upgrade() {
            Some(target_pointer) => Ok(Some(target_pointer)),
            None => Err("Target object was dropped".to_string())
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Child {
    pub id: u32
}
impl Target for Child {
    fn get_target(&self) -> Result<Option<Arc<Mutex<dyn Target>>>, String> {
        Ok(None)
    }
}


fn main() {
    // Create object instances
    let child  = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Child { id: 4 }));
    let parent = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Parent { id: 2, target: None }));

    // Assign targets
    parent.try_lock().unwrap().assign_target(&child);

    // Print pointer memory addresses
    println!("Original pointer:                    {:p}", Arc::as_ptr(&child));
    println!("Upgraded pointer assigned to parent: {:p}", Arc::as_ptr(&parent.try_lock()
                                                                             .unwrap()
                                                                             .get_target()
                                                                             .unwrap()
                                                                             .unwrap()));
    println!("Cloned and casted pointer:           {:p}", Arc::as_ptr(&(child.clone() as Arc<Mutex<dyn Target>>)));
    println!("");

    // Compare the target assigned and a direct
    // casted clone of the original object.
    assert_eq!(Arc::as_ptr(&parent.try_lock().unwrap().get_target().unwrap().unwrap()),
               Arc::as_ptr(&(child.clone() as Arc<Mutex<dyn Target>>)));
}


This is the error message I'm getting:
Original pointer:                    0x17308dcab70
Upgraded pointer assigned to parent: 0x17308dcab70
Cloned and casted pointer:           0x17308dcab70

thread 'main' panicked at src\main.rs:68:5:
assertion `left == right` failed
  left: 0x17308dcab70
 right: 0x17308dcab70
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

What am I doing wrong? If it's of any help, I'm currently on stable Rust v.1.77.2. This error persisted even when executed on multiple computers.

Weird. I'm not getting the assertion failure when running this code on the Rust Playground, which runs on Linux. Which target are you running your code on? Note also that there's Arc::ptr_eq, which might do a better job of giving the desired result. Specifically, the doc says: "This function ignores the metadata of dyn Trait pointers."

That's because you're comparing wide pointers, and comparing wide pointers also compares the metadatas, in your case, the vtables. And vtables can be duplicated for many reasons - for example, different CGU (Code Gen Units).
You can fix that with Arc::ptr_eq(), or std::ptr::addr_eq().
